# Parse html meta keywords using regex

Tags: c#, html, regex, parsing, dom

I need to parse html meta keywords using regex. Source string is always in same format like:

```
<meta name="description" content="description text">
<meta name="keywords" content="Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3...">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/xml+rss" href="http://example.com/rss">
```

I wont to get Keyword1, Keyword2 and Keyword3 as List < string >

Comment: Do not use a regex. Use an HTMLParser like [HTMLAgilityPack](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

if you're looking for a simple regex solution and your input isn't complex then you can try this

`<meta\b[^>]*\bname=["]keywords["][^>]*\bcontent=(['"]?)((?:[^,>"'],?){1,})\1[>]` which will pull the value in the content field.

[image]

Group 1 is the open quote, which would then be required to close at the end of the value.
Group 2 is the contents which could then be split on the comma.

## Disclaimer

This expression could fail on some simple edge cases which is why regex shouldn't be used for parsing HTML, instead you should look to use a html parsing engine.

## C# Example

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myapp
{
  class Class1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
          Regex re = new Regex(@"<meta\b[^>]*\bname=[""]keywords[""][^>]*\bcontent=(['""]?)((?:[^,>""'],?){1,})\1[>]",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
          MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
          int mIdx=0;
          foreach (Match m in mc)
           {
            for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
              }
            mIdx++;
          }
        }
    }
}

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <meta name="keywords" content="Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3...">
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3...
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex is not a good choice for parsing HTML files..

HTML is not strict nor is it regular with its format..

Use [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

You can use this code to retrieve all Keywords using `HtmlAgilityPack`

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://yourWebSite.com");

List<String> keyLst= doc.DocumentNode
                        .SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name='keywords']")
                        .Attributes["content"].Value
                        .Split(',').ToList();
```

`keyLst` now contain all Keywords

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could comment instead of submitting this as an answer, but my rep is too low :(

I understand the need to perform regex sometimes, but as everyone else recommends, it's just preferred to use a standard XML or HTML parser.  It's safer in terms of encompassing unintended input variations and can even be faster.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/701177/1002098